# PHP 7.0.9/NGINX 1.11.3/Magento 2.1.0 Admin 404

Tags: magento2, nginx, 404-page, php-7, centos

We have a Linux CentOS 7 server with PHP 7.0.9 and NGINX 1.11.3 installed.
We have completed the command line installation of Magento 2.1.0.
The front end loads up just fine in the browser but when I try to go to the admin back end, I am getting a 404 error page.
I have been scouring the internet for a solution and none of the solutions I have found have fixed my issue.
Please help!

Thanks

Comment: is there any errors in browser console?

Comment: @MagenX there are no errors in the browser console and there are no errors in both the NGINX logs and the Magento logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Magento installation directory and open /app/etc/env.php file

```
return array (
  ‘backend’ => 
  array (
    ‘frontName’ => ‘siteadmin’, //change the frontName here to change the Admin URL
  )
```

Clear the cache using the following command or by removing all files from var/cache

```
rm -rf var/cache
```

That’s it, now you have the new Magento admin URL. As you can see changing Admin URL in Magento 2 can’t be easier

Comment: I have tried changing the "frontName" and clearing the cache folder and the admin back end still gives a 404 error page.

Comment: Try in firefox and clear the browser cache. if possible comment your admin URL

Comment: I have tried in Firefox and cleared my cache and it's still not working.